# insert record id with characters and unique numbers

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 mysql database tables

table 1

categories  [ category_id, category_parent, category_name, property_for ]

example record   [ 12, Hurghada, Villa, Sale ]

table 2

Pages   [ page_id, category_parent, category_name, page_name]

example record   [ 10, Hurghada, Villa, New villa for sale at Hurghada ]

at my CMS need to insert new records to pages table under the selected category so at the insert page i wrote

```
$query_rsCategory = "SELECT * FROM categories 
    WHERE category_id ='".trim($_REQUEST['category_id'])."'";
```

at my insert form i wrote

```
<input name="page_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $query_rsCategory 
     ['category_parent']; echo $query_rsCategory ['category_name '];
echo $query_rsCategory ['property_for']; ?>-" >
```

now when i insert new record page_id will be " HurghadaVillaSale-"

but what i'm trying to do is "HVS-45"

and for next insert under the same category "HVS-46"

only first Character of each value then - unique Number

i'd appreciate if someone can tell me how to echo the first Character only also make the number auto integrated unique

Comment: Please use the code syntax with `

Comment: i just Edit my post so items will show , is it more clear now ?

Comment: what are the types of the table columns?

Comment: page_id type is int(11) with AUTO_INCREMENT the other columns are varchar

Comment: if `page_id` is type `int auto_increment`, why are you trying to make a `varchar` value for it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

`$query_rsCategory 
     ['category_parent']=substr($query_rsCategory 
     ['category_parent'],0,1);`

Do the same process for the other two

Comment: hi ganeshrj thanks for your answer i used your code but it ignored it and give a number then i unchecked AUTO_INCREMENT at the database table for column page_id then when i insert it gives a value of 0 insert again says duplicate primary key ! do i need to use echo ?

Comment: `GetSQLValueString($_POST['page_id'], "int"),`

Comment: Please take out GetSQLValueString as it removes all the character added.. use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: value="'$row_rsParent['city_name_en']=substr($row_rsParent ['city_name_en'],0,1); echo $row_rsParent['city_name_en']; '"